# Tor can't be installed on Whonix GPG download signature could not be verified

Tags: windows, help, whonix, error, virtual-machine

I have virtualbox installed on w7 and there installed the gateway and the workstation. Now if I want to use the Tor browser it says it's not installed and if I want to install it. Then I get this error message which I have searched for around the web but can't find anything about it.

[image: scrshot]!

Really hope someone can help me out or has a workaround because I really want to use it. Have had a lot of setbacks today and yesterday so it would be fine to finally do some work.

**UPDATE**

I've already tried using what you said.
The result of gpg --recv-keys "$fpr":

```
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg` created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf` created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf` are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg` created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` created
gpg: no keyserver know (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad URI
```

So it goes wrong here.

Comment: Try: gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys "$fpr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when your whonix version is 9.4 or below. It is a known bug that will be fixed in version 9.6. For now, here is how you can fix it:

Open a terminal in Whonix, then copy & paste the following lines into it:

`fpr="916B8D99C38EAF5E8ADC7A2A8D66066A2EEACCDA"
gpg --recv-keys "$fpr"
gpg --fingerprint "$fpr" 
gpg --export "$fpr" | sudo apt-key add -`

After that, you'll have to update your system using:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

After that, you will be able to install or update the TorBrowser.

Note that it is advisable to reboot the system after finishing the system update.

For more information about the system update procedure and certain advices about it, see https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Security_Guide#Updates.

Comment: See my update for more info to see what's wrong when I try that